# Height is not changing/working on my website

Tags: html, css

My height is not changing on my slideshow.

I have tried height, min-height and max height. I have also checked on here and google, but nothing is working.

HTML :

```
<div class="container show">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                    <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Chicago</h3>
                    <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>New York</h3>
                    <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show{
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    position: fixed
}
```

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write down how you want to get a result?

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical description of a problem. From what I see, it's working as it should.

Comment: @ariferol01 I wand the height of the slideshow to be smaller

Comment: It is smaller. In fact, it's 100px tall.

Comment: can you try this? `<div class="show"><div class="container">bla bla bla</div></div>`

Comment: @Rob The height is half the page. That is not exactly 100px tall

Comment: No. The height is exactly 100px.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the style tag from all img elements:

```
<img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
->
<img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Chicago">
```

and try again with height width max-height and max-width;

try to not use style tags in html and css simultaneously if you can;

if you need to style all img tags just use

```
CSS:
img{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file -

```
.item{
height: 100px;
}
```

It will work perfectly fine.. hope it helps! :)

Comment: He said he tried it and it did not work for him so, no, it will not "work 100%".

Comment: Bro.. you try it and see. It will work. Just go to any carousal example on w3school website. Then add my code in style tag. The height will change.( He didnt tried my code yet!!)

Comment: The very second sentence in his post says he tried `height` but he has not figured out, yet, why he thinks it's not sitting at 100px right now.

Comment: Because you have to set height of item class , not the whole container. See my code properly. He has set the height to whole container. Thats why carousal height was not changing.

Comment: No, that's not his issue. His issue is that he doesn't know that `height` only works on the content box. I tried to prod him along in the comments but I guess he has abandoned the question.